# Filter table, copy and paste into multiple existing workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has data for multiple projects.

I need to filter the data (by project number), then copy and paste each project's data into separate existing workbooks ( I have a tab that contains file paths of the each workbook and project names.

I have managed to open the first project's workbook, copy and paste, save and close the workbook but excel throw an error after that.

I know there is an issue but not too sure how to fix it.

Can anyone help?

Below is a link to the files

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mBtMO_oBqHHTFLcNVe-Us_zgmmMZ3DeA?usp=sharing)

```
Sub OpenProjects()


Dim N As String
Dim LAST As Integer
Dim TABLE As Range
Dim PNumber As String 'Project Number



LAST = Sheets("Projects").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


Set TABLE = Sheets("Projects").Range("A1:M" & LAST)


'Open files

Sheets("Unique Projects").Select

RowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("unique Projects").Range("B:B"))


For i = 2 To RowCount

N = Sheets("Unique projects").Cells(i, 2)

Workbooks.Open (N)



    'Back to original workbook



Workbooks("original.xlsm").Activate

For Each NUMBER In Sheets("Unique Projects").Range([A2], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

With TABLE
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=NUMBER.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(NUMBER & ".xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

End With

Workbooks(NUMBER & ".xlsm").Save
Workbooks(NUMBER & ".xlsm").Close

Workbooks("Original").Activate



Next NUMBER


Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: where do you get PNumber from?

Comment: Sorry, that should not be there.

Comment: Then what is NUMBER? initially it'd be the cell in the range. You could use option explicit at the top of the module so you prevent from using undeclared variables. in this case, seems like you could have an empty cell and maybe that is raising the error. One suggestion: 1) edit your question and add a screenshot of the data (or a sample) where and how you have project names and paths

Comment: `Number` is defined as a String. In `For Each Number` *Number* is an object because `Each` is always an object. Select *Number* in your code and press F1 to learn which object you are referring to. It isn't what you hoped to do. When you assign names to your variables, especially short, convenient and obvious names, always use F1 to check whether a MS engineer had the same idea before you and you are, in fact, using a reserved word.

Comment: What error? in what line? "I have managed to open the first project's workbook, copy and paste, save and close the workbook but excel throw an error after that."

Comment: Hi.  Here is a link to the files.  Sorry I am new to the website so still learning my way around.  Thanks.   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mBtMO_oBqHHTFLcNVe-Us_zgmmMZ3DeA?usp=sharing

Comment: There are at least 2 approach to your goal. 1: Open each file from **Unique Projects** then filter & copy relevant rows from **Projects**. 2: Make copies of **Projects** to new workbook, then Delete irrelevant rows from bottom. Do you manually create the **Unique Projects** from the **Projects** sheet?

Comment: I can get all workbooks to open then copy, paste, save, and close.  But the issue is each project doc I am planning to use are very large so I can't have 50 project workbooks open at the same.  So I need to open each project workbook, then filter the table in the master doc then copy, paste, save, and close each workbook.  Please see attached files.

Comment: I have another macro built in the master workbook that generates unique project numbers.